# Any downsides of upgrading MacBook Pro 13 mid-2012 low-end model to 16GB?

Tags: memory, upgrade, macbook-pro

- First of all is it possible with core i5 not core i7?
- More RAM eats more battery, but I'm not sure how much? Will it reduce my battery life by 1-2 hours and I will have 5 hours instead of 7?
- Is performance of installed memory(both are 1600MHz) the same on all benchmarks? Is it possible that the CPU doesn't work so fast with large memory?
- How good MACOS system utilization of 16GB of memory?
- Officially MacBook support 8GB. Will upgrade to 16GB void warranty?
- Additional heat

Are these downsides correct or am I missing something here?

Comment: You never really need to worry about RAM power. It's very small. Heat as well is minimal

Comment: What do you use your MacBook for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum memory of the Macbook Pro 13" mid-2012 model is apparently [8GB](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT1270#link1), so one of your questions is moot.

The RAM is [designed to be upgraded](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT1270#link1) by the end user, so you will not void your warranty by doing so.

Any difference in battery life will likely be measured in seconds.

Comment: But there are a lot of users who did such upgrade. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4002478?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: OK. But it's not officially supported, so do it at your own risk. :)

Comment: DO you think it can void warranty?

Comment: It won't void the warranty. As Michael rightly said , it is designed to be upgraded by the end user.

Answer (score 1):

First of all is it possible with core i5 not core i7?
   **It is possible .**

More RAM eats more battery, but I'm not sure how much? Will it reduce my battery life by 1-2 hours and I will have 5 hours instead of 7?

**It will eat more battery, but not in hours. So don't worry about it. All your RAM won't be in use all the time.**

Is performance of installed memory(both are 1600MHz) the same on all benchmarks? Probably CPU works not so fast with large memory...

**No comments.**

How good MACOS system utilization of 16GB of memmory?

**MAC OS can utilize 16GB of RAM, but its not the question about the OS, how many softwares are available which can utilize more than 8GB of RAM effectively. Unless you are planning to use Adobe Premiere or Final cut pro X, i would suggest you go with 8GB RAM**

Seems like it should not void my Waranty. Is there cases when it void warranty?

**Not if you just upgrade / replace the memory with a branded one.**

Comment: I plan to use memory for my Java programs.
Why no comments about perfrmance? Will geekbanch show same performance with orignal 4gb configuration and new 16GB?

Comment: no comments in the sense, i didn't want to comment on something i wasn't sure about. i am not sure about the performance gauging tools. If i can't see visible performance in my applications, i wouldn't consider the upgrade worth it. I have used a machine with 16GB at office for Video editing and my home machine is 8GB, except while rendering and editing i never found the machine craving for more than 8GB. About the geekbench , i guess it should show marginal difference between the configurations.